# how would i get it to show me records in one table that arent present in another table using an EQUI JOIN?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT C.CustomerNo, Name, Telephone, address, postcode
FROM Customer AS C, CarForSale AS S
WHERE NOT (C.CustomerNo=S.CustomerNo);
```

So I'm meant to produce output which shows customers that currently do not have a record in car for sale table. i thought of putting in NOT in the WHERE clause to essentialy bring up the ones that arent there but it's just bringing up the whole table back.

Comment: Use NOT EXISTS or NOT IN operator. Or you can perform a LEFT OUTER JOIN and select the rows that fail to find a right partner.

Comment: Can't use a LEFT OUTER JOIN, Lecturer only taught us equi join and I want to get as many marks as possible. can you give me an example of NOT EXISTS or NOT IN. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Actually, there is a slight modification for MS Access, because it does not support `CROSS JOIN`.  So, only use commas when you intend `CROSS JOIN`.

You cannot do what you want with an `INNER JOIN`.  You can use a `LEFT JOIN`, which is still an equi-join:

```
SELECT C.CustomerNo, Name, Telephone, address, postcode
FROM Customer AS C LEFT JOIN
     CarForSale AS S
     ON C.CustomerNo = S.CustomerNo
WHERE S.CustomerNo IS NULL;
```

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table, even when the `ON` clause is not true.  The `WHERE` clause chooses the rows that have no match.

Comment: Why don't teachers explain things like this!? Thank you very much, you have saved me a huge headache